# In python, whats the most efficient way to apply function to a list

Tags: python, list, function

my actual data is huge and quite heavy. But if I simplify and say if I have a list of numbers 
`x = [1,3,45,45,56,545,67]`

and I have a function that performs some action on these numbers?

```
def sumnum(x):
    return(x=np.sqrt(x)+1)
```

whats the best way apply this function to the list? I dont want to apply for loop. Would 'map' be the best option or anything faster/ efficient than that?

thanks,
Prasad

Comment: That function isn't valid syntax.

Comment: How you're applying the function will probably be the smallest part of your problem; it'll most certainly depend on the structure of the data and how you're able to stream it to memory - either by handling each element by itself or by batching it up. You'll simply have to try - there isn't an answer that fits every use case.

Comment: what's wrong with `return np.sqrt(x)+1`?

Comment: `map`, for loop, list comprehensions, they will be all in the same ballpark of performance. You aren't getting around looping. Why don't you just want to use a loop?

Comment: I would have thought loops would be more inefficient for heavy data..?

Answer (score 0):

In standard Python, the `map` function is probably the easiest way to apply a function to an array (not sure about efficiency though). However, if your array is huge, as you mentioned, you may want to look into using [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), which is very similar to Python's built-in `map` function.

Edit: A possible code sample:

```
vsumnum = np.vectorize(sumnum)
x = vsumnum(x)
```

The first function call returns a function which is vectorized, meaning that numpy has prepared it to be mapped to your array, and the second function call actually applies the function to your array and returns the resulting array. **Taken from the docs, this method is provided for convenience, not efficiency and is basically the same as a for loop**

Edit 2:
As @Ch3steR mentioned, numpy also allows for elementwise operations to arrays, so in this case because you are doing simple operations, you can just do np.sqrt(x) + 1, which will add 1 to the square root of each element. Functions like `map` and `numpy.vectorize` are better for when you have more complicated operations to apply to an array

Comment: thanks @awarrier99, I will have a look. Although i increasingly feel maps might be more suitable for my problem but good to know about numpy.vectorize function as well!

Comment: @PrasKam no problem. I myself only recently discovered `numpy.vectorize` so I thought it may be good to mention as well

Comment: from the docs of `np.vectorize` : _The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop._
consider editing the answer to highlight that